# What is the actual ratings of this limit switch?

Tags: switches, maximum-ratings

I'm going to use this microswitches as the limit cut off for motorized locking system for sliding door of my store room under the stair case.

Upon checking it properly, the Indonesian made Omron switch marked with three different voltage ratings and current ratings. Im my application the switches will be handling about 2Amps peak at 24V. All the markings are above these thus I will not having trouble using these switches but still I'm very much confused what exactly the specs are for this units.

[image]

Comment: Here is the [datasheet](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-ss.pdf)

Comment: From the datasheet; SS-5GL means 125V 5A Hinged Lever.  Then why there are also 250V  markings stamped on it?

Comment: @soosaisteven Also in the datasheet lol. Look on Page 4, left side under **Ratings**. Consider looking at Brhans answer below as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markings/ratings you look at and work with depend on which approval/testing/listing agency you're most concerned with.
The 5A/125VAC, 3A/250VAC ratings have been tested/approved/listed by [UL](https://www.ul.com/) and/or [CSA](https://www.csagroup.org/).
The 5A/250V~ rating has been tested/approved/listed by some other agency who's mark I am not immediately familiar with.

Since in your application you're only planning to work with 2A/24V, and you're presumably not planning to sell your device (at least not into any market where approval from one of these agencies is required), you should be well within the limits of all of these ratings and you shouldn't see any problems using this switch (but do take care to protect it from back-EMF spikes if you're switching an inductive load).